# How to access the transcluded scope of a directive from within it's preLink method

Tags: angularjs, scope

lately I realized that for a directive with `scope: true, transclude: true` angular creates one scope for the directive and one scope for the transcluded content (even if the group's scope is isolate, the behavious is the same - two scopes (the isolate + the transcluded)). Then all the elements that are nested in this directive are using this transcluded scope, or if the nested element is another directive with `scope: true`, then this directive's parent scope is again the transcluded scope.

I have a problem with this behaviour and to illustrate it, please immagine this example:
1. Imagine we have a directive "group" that has `scope: true, transclude: true`. This directive is to serve as container for other directives with `scope: true`.
2. Imagine we have a directive "element" that has `scope: true`

Now consider the example usage:

```
<group element-label="My Element">
    <element></element>
</group>
```

Generally what I want to achieve is to make "element" aware of the element-label property of "group" and I want to set groupID value (immagine that I have a way to calculate it!) inside the transcluded scope so "element"'s scope will be able to see it.
Inside the preLink function the scope that is injected is the group's scope is not the transcluded one, so I cannot set neither the element-label, nor the groupID to the transcluded scope there. And i need this information in the transcluded scope, because only from there "element" will see it.

I think that from "element"'s scope I can do:

```
$scope.$parent.$$prevSubling
```

But it does not seem appropriate for me.

Can someone please advice me, what is the way to pass information from "group" to "element" in this case, where I need to use transclusion?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `require` the controller of the `group` directive.

Long answer:

1. Have `group` implement a controller:

   ```
   return { // directive "group"
       ...
       controller: function($scope, ...) {
           ...
       }
   };
   ```
2. Have `element` require the parent `group`:

   ```
   return { // directive "element"
       ...
       require: "^group",
       link: function(scope,elem,attrs,groupCtrl) {
           ...
       }
   };
   ```
3. The controller of `group` should provide methods to expose the information or functionality you want:

   ```
   return { // directive "group"
       ...
       controller: function($scope, ...) {
           ...
           this.getData = function() {
               ...
           };

           this.doSomething = function(x) {
               ...
           };
       }
   };
   ```
4. Use those methods from the `element`, either to pass data or to retrieve:

   ```
       // directive "element"
       link: function(scope,elem,attrs,groupCtrl) {
           var data = groupCtrl.getData();
           var ourData = ...
           groupCtrl.doSomething(ourData);
       }
   ```

Comment: Paraskevop. Thank you for the answer. I believe that this might help me in case nothing else come to mind, but what I don't like about this approach is that "element" will "require" group to exist at all. And that is totally not expected for me. I will dig some more into that. Thanks again for the proposed solution!

Comment: You can use the `require: "?^group"` syntax to require the group controller *optionally*. In this case you will have to check the 4th argument of the `link` function for `null`.

Comment: Ok, that's a new trick! Thanks for the answer that will solve my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Transclusion scope is nothing special - it participates in scope inheritance, like any other normal scope. The only difference is that it contains transcluded contents.   So that means that in this scenario:

```
<group element-label="My Element">
    <element></element>
</group>
```

The `element` directive is already *aware* of group's scope through prototypical scope inheritance.  You can take advantage of this:

```
app.directive('group', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true, // create a child scope
        controller: function(scope, element, attr) {
              // put element-label attribute in group scope
              scope.elementLabel = attr.elementLabel;
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in your `element` attribute, you know that `elementLabel` exists in parent scope.

```
app.directive('element', function() {
    return  {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true, // create a child scope
        require: '^group', // group directive is required 
        template: '<div id="{{$parent.elementLabel}}Element">blah</div>',
        controller: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var elementLabel = scope.$parent.elementLabel; // from parent
            // do something else with elementLabel...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe that this might help me in case nothing else come to mind, but what I don't like about this approach is that "element" will "require" group to exist at all. And that is totally not expected for me. I will dig some more into that. Thanks again for the proposed solution!